# SCSS load order in Angular 7

Tags: angular, sass

Global styles are going in to "src/styles.scss", contents of styles.scss:

```
// bs variables
@import '../src/assets/scss/variables';

// importing bootstrap
@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
```

i import there BS's "_variables.scss", then in my component "Login" (login.component.scss), i'm trying to use a variable from "_variables.scss", but it won't see this variable.

What load order of scss files are in angular? Or what's the correct place to import variables file?

**UPDATE 1**

Contents of login.component.scss:

```
#login {
  background-color: $blue;
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

as @Drenai pointed me regarding `assets` directory, i've placed my `_variables.scss` under `src/_variables.scss`, then imported it in `styles.scss`, but variables won't work in my `login.component.scss` if i don't explicitly import it there. But why do i have to import it in a `login.component.scss` if it's imported in `styles.scss` already?

**UPDATE 3**

Just found and old issue: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/3700
seems like there's no other way, we have to import variables in every component. Or use CSS variables.

Comment: Is `/src/assets/scss/variables` your own variables file? If so, it shouldn't be in the assets folder - as it will be bundled with your app at build time - not loaded at runtime. I'll give you more info based on that. Add in some of your `LoginComponent` scss import code too so we can see it

Comment: Yes, in "src/assets/scss/_variables.scss". If it shouldn't be there, then where do i put it?

Comment: Wherever you want, you could have a "styles" folder in `src/app` for example.

Comment: @AntoineB, that's a mess. What's the purpose of `src/assets`, it should contain assets - images, icons, styles. Don't understand.

Comment: It should contain images and icons, and maybe the CSS or JavaScript from external libraries that cannot be imported using NPM. Your CSS is part of your app, and it'll be bundled with the CSS files compiled by angular when running the application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's good to have a `styles` folder: I've used the following structure a good bit:

```
src/styles
> _variables.scss
> styles.scss
```

Create a `styles` folder, and put your main `styles.scss` in there, and add:

```
@import 'variables.scss'; // includes font-awesome path
```

In your `login.component.scss`, also use `@import 'variables.scss';`

#### Update `angular.json`

You'll need to replace any lines that have `src/styles.scss` with `src/styles/styles.scss`

Depending on what you have in your `angular.json` already you might need to add the following to the `options` of the `"architect"` and `"test"` sections:

```
"stylePreprocessorOptions": {
              "includePaths": [
                "src/styles"
              ]
            },
```

**Note:** you wouldn't put it in `assets` folder because that's for *static* assets, such as images that you need to reference yourself. Your styles will automatically be bundled into a single file and added `dist` folder during the Angular build process

**Angular Wiki**: There's a good article about this on the [Angular CLI Stories](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-global-styles) page

Comment: It's nice, but i would need to import my variables file in every component then, that's tedious.

Comment: But what if i just add my `_variables.scss`  in `angular.json` right in `styles` array?

Comment: @AlexanderKim The thing is that `_variables` are not actually styles at all. The `scss` processor takes each variable and uses them when building the styles, and then the `_variables` simply get discarded. They will never actually appear in the browser source

Comment: Okay, so order is the following: 1st loaded all styles from `src/styles.scss`, then appended components local styles, like `login.component.scss`, right?

Comment: Yes. The `styles.scss` will be loaded first - Angular adds a `<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.3747e9cf429eb2ff461e.css">` to the very top of the `index.html` which is the bundled styles. The component's styles are added dynamically by the JavaScript as you load each view - and they appear as `<style>....</style>` elements in the `index.html` (if you open DevTools you can see them being added as you navigate through your app)

Comment: But one last thing i still don't get, if i did `@import 'variables'` in `styles.scss`, then why do i need to import it inside a component's style? Isn't `styles.scss` is GLOBAL?